# Return False if variable isn't boolean

Tags: c#, boolean

How can I the code below to return `False` if `usable` is anything other than `True` (anything other than `bool`), currently my code throws an exception `usable` is not a bool.

```
if (!Boolean.Parse(readValue("Useable"))) return true;
return (defined.ContainsKey(key) || (key == "Useable"));
```

Comment: You errr ah... Spelled usable incorrectly...

Comment: The code is from a previous employee but I hadn't spotted the spelling error! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
bool isUseable;
bool.TryParse(readValue("Useable"), out isUseable);
```

Comment: Should be bool.TryParse(readValue("Useable"), out isTrue), but otherwise I would do it the same way.

Comment: There's no point initialising `isUseable` in this code.  You can remove the assignment -- it's misleading.

Comment: @Drew: not sure about "misleading". If anything, it's more explicit, but perhaps superfluous. I've removed it.

Comment: `Boolean.TryParse` is much slower than a simple string comparison - please see my answer.

Comment: @Andrew: looking at Boolean.TryParse in reflector, it does exactly the same string comparison you're doing, so I have to question your benchmark results.

Comment: @Kent -- I chose the word misleading because it implies (perhaps to a more novice programmer) that the value specified in the initialiser remains if the parse fails.  Consider the scenario that you'd initialised it to `true` instead.  I've debugged errors in other people's code due to this on a few occasions, which is why I mention it.

Answer (score 7):

This is the simplest and fastest approach:

```
return "True".Equals(readValue("Useable"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

**Note:** `Boolean.TryParse` is *not* a good choice as it is significantly slower than a simple string comparison.  Please see the results of this test (using [Jon Skeet's BenchmarkHelper)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/26/benchmarking-made-easy.aspx):

```
using System;
using BenchmarkHelper;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var results = TestSuite.Create
                ("Boolean.TryParse vs. String comparison", "True", true)
            .Add(tryParse)
            .Add(stringComparison)
            .RunTests()
            .ScaleByBest(ScalingMode.VaryDuration);

        results.Display(ResultColumns.NameAndDuration | ResultColumns.Score,
                results.FindBest());        
    }

    static Boolean tryParse(String input)
    {
        Boolean result;
        Boolean.TryParse(input, out result);
        return result;
    }

    static Boolean stringComparison(String input)
    {
        return "True".Equals(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
============ Boolean.TryParse vs. String comparison ============
tryParse         12.118 6.03
stringComparison 21.895 1.00
```

Comment: +1 There's no need to do parsing here (if I understand the original question correctly). With this snippet, I would probably invert the syntax so there isn't a function call on a string literal, though.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question but what is the unit of the time value? Is seems that stringComparison uses more time than tryParse or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: @Jon - What's wrong with a method call on a string literal?  If you inverted the syntax you could potentially end up with a `NullReferenceException` if the result of `readValue("Useable")` was `null`.

Comment: @Lazarus - Not a stupid question at all.  From http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/26/benchmarking-made-easy.aspx: "A benchmark result has a duration and an iteration count, as well as the descriptive name of the test which was run to produce the result. Results can be scaled so that either the duration or the iteration count matches another result. Likewise a result has a score, which is simply the duration (in ticks, but it's pretty arbitrary) divided by the iteration count...

Comment: ...  Again, the score can be retrieved in a scaled fashion, using a specified result as a "standard" with a scaled score of 1.0. Lower is always better."

Comment: I have to question this benchmark. Crack open reflector and look at Boolean.TryParse. It does exactly that string comparison logic for you.

Comment: @Kent - Very interesting! I will have to re-evaluate this!

Comment: It's a nice, concise solution regardless.

Comment: tsk tskm, magic constants. That's what Boolean.TrueString is for.

Answer (score 5):

```
bool isUseable;
if (bool.TryParse(readValue("Useable"), out isUseable))
    return isUseable;
return false;
```

Comment: You could shorten this code to: `return bool.TryParse(readValue("Useable"), out isUseable) && isUseable;`  ...personally I find that more readable.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
return (readValue("Useable") == "TRUE");
```

EDITED as a result of Drew's comment

Comment: That's a very good point Drew... answering in the middle of other things!

Comment: You might also use string.Equals(readValue("Useable"), "TRUE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) as the poster doesn't indicate what case the return value would be. Ordinal comparisons are faster too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Equals(true, myobject);
```